# Resource temporarily unavailable (Timeout::Error) cucumber visit only on jenkins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber

call to visit some_path fails consistently on ubuntu / jenkins with `Resource temporarily unavailable (Timeout::Error)`, but passes consistently locally on mac.  Tried every suggestion I could find online... no luck.  Anyone ever run into this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is only thing that worked.  I tried Around hooks... nothing.  M-I-C K-E-Y M-O-U-S-E...

```
  def short_bus_visit( url )
    10.times do |i| 
      begin
        visit url 
        break
      rescue Exception
        next
      end 
    end 
  end
```